# Mock http.Client in Dart gives exception

Tags: dart, mockito, dart-http, dart-mock

I have a problem when testing my classes that make http requests.
I want to Mock the client so that every time the client makes a request, I can answer with a Mocked response.
At the moment my code looks like this:

```
  final fn = MockClientHandler;
  final client = MockClient(fn as Future<Response> Function(Request));

  when(client.get(url)).thenAnswer((realInvocation) async =>
    http.Response('{"userId": 1, "id": 2, "title": "mock"}', 200));
```

However, when I run the test I get the following exception:
`type '_FunctionType' is not a subtype of type '(Request) => Future<Response>' in type cast test/data_retrieval/sources/fitbit_test.dart 26:32  main`

According to Flutter/Dart Mockito should be used like this:

```
 final client = MockClient();

  // Use Mockito to return a successful response when it calls the
  // provided http.Client.
  when(client.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1')))
      .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response('{"userId": 1, "id": 2, "title":"mock"}', 200));
```

In the example, the client is mocked without parameters, but I guess this has been changed since the documentation of MockClient now also accepts a parameter.
I have no idea why this exception occurs and nothing can be found on the internet, so I was wondering if someone here knows why this exception is happening.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is from `final fn = MockClientHandler;` and later you do `fn as Future<Response> Function(Request)`.  What is `MockClientHandler`?  It sounds like it's a `typedef` (which would make it a *type*) and not an instance of a `Function`, which would cause the cast to fail.

Comment: But when I don't add the cast it gives a compilation error: `The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Response> Function(Request)'.` Could you help me with how the cast should look like then?

Comment: You missed the point.  `final fn = MockClientHandler;` is what's wrong. (It's ultimately a useless assignment.  There isn't much that you can meaningful do with `fn` afterward.) Once again: what is `MockClientHandler`?  It's unclear what you expect `fn` to be.

Comment: Ah, `MockClient` and `MockClientHandler` are provided by `package:http`'s  testing library.  As I suspcted, you need to provide an actual function.

Answer (score 5):

`package:http`'s [`MockClient`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http.testing/MockClient-class.html) is a bit of a misnomer.  It's not really a mock (and it's certainly not related to `package:mockito`'s `Mock`); it's more like a *stub* (or arguably a fake): it has an implementation that is meant to simulate a normal `http.Client` object.

Note that Flutter's [Mockito examples](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/mocking) create a `MockClient` object using `package:mockito`, but **this is unrelated to the `MockClient` class provided by `package:http` itself**.

> ```dart
> final fn = MockClientHandler;
> final client = MockClient(fn as Future<Response> Function(Request));
> ```

`package:http`'s `MockClient` expects an *instance* of a `MockClientHandler` as an argument, but you are attempting to pass the `MockClientHandler` *type* itself.  You are expected to provide an actual function (again, because `MockClient` has an actual implementation).

In other words, if you want to use `package:http`'s `MockClient`, then you should do:

```dart
Future<Response> requestHandler(Request request) async {
   return http.Response('{"userId": 1, "id": 2, "title": "mock"}', 200));
}

final client = MockClient(requestHandler);
```

Or if you want to use `package:mockito`, you need to follow https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/mocking *exactly* and *generate* a Mockito-based `MockClient` class.

Comment: for mockito: ^5.0.17 , giving this error The function 'MockClient' isn't defined.

Comment: @B.shruti And did you follow the instructions to generate the mock classes?

Comment: Followed each and every step suggested in https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/unit/mocking

Answer (score 0):

This is what the doc's fetch_album_test.dart will look like when they get around to updating it! (tests pass)...

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/testing.dart';
import 'package:mocking/main.dart';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';

// Generate a MockClient using the Mockito package.
// Create new instances of this class in each test.
@GenerateMocks([http.Client])
void main() {
  group('fetchAlbum', () {
    test('returns an Album if the http call completes successfully', () async {
      final client = MockClient((_) async =>
          http.Response('{"userId": 1, "id": 2, "title": "mock"}', 200));

      expect(await fetchAlbum(client), isA<Album>());
    });

    test('throws an exception if the http call completes with an error', () {
      final client = MockClient((_) async => http.Response('Not Found', 404));

      expect(fetchAlbum(client), throwsException);
    });
  });
}
```